# Algorithm/pattern to translate a search phrase from user input into SQL query

Tags: java, mysql, sql, search

I have been trying to create a Java app that prompts the user to enter a search sentence and the app should take the sentence and translate it into an appropriate sql query to be executed and retrieve the correct info from a SQL database.

A simple example of an input could be:

```
"Japanese restaurants in Toronto"
```

The app should translate that into:

```
SELECT * FROM Restaurants WHERE s_city = 'Toronto' AND s_type = 'Japanese';
```

or something along those lines.

So far my app takes away all the irrelevant words such as the word "in" from the example and then I would analyse each word (with a lot of if statements) to decide what each word should translate to. (table name, a column name, a where clause etc) Then a query is built based on the results.

From the example, the code would know that the word restaurant is a name of one of my tables in the database therefore the query would have `FROM Restaurants`, while the words "Japanese" and "Toronto" would be identified as possible values of a column of the Restaurant table therefore adding where clauses to the query: `WHERE s_city = 'Toronto' AND s_type = 'Japanese' ;`

The problem is that my code is not very robust. I built it using a lot of if statements as a start but as I expanded my code I kept encountering more and more different scenarios while my code gets messier and messier to a point it becomes really hard to maintain whenever I discover a bug.

I wish to know if there is a certain pattern out there that deals with translating literal search entries from user input into sql queries. Or if anyone could suggest a better approach to attack this problem that would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: That's a *really* open-ended question.  There is a whole branch of computer science (Natural Language Processing) dedicated to solving this problem.  How deep into that rabbit hole do you want to go?

Comment: You could restrict the input of your users and use them as search parameters so they are more well-formed. Why give yourself more work of having to preprocess the queries?

Comment: My database is fairly small with only 3 tables. So I am guessing not too deep. But I would love to know a good pattern to tackle this problem.

Comment: It is much easier for you and for the user to use a GUI than natural text.

Comment: The most common design pattern for these types of situations is called the Think A Little And Use Your Problem Solving Skills Pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Anon has mentioned: You will run the whole way down  text mining and NLP (Natural Language Processing). Let's give a short abstract and some key words to search for.

First, do you know the **language** of the input? If yes, you're a lucky guy. If no, you can gues it out of the character set used (is it arabic, latin, chinese? If latin, are any special accent characters like äöü used?) and out of the words, that you can compare with words of different languages in dictinonaries.

When comparing words, keep in mind that the user might have misspelled it. So you must **compare for similarity**. You can use for example [Levenshtein-Distanz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) to get similarity of two words.

Then, you must **eliminate stop words**. Stop words are the simple little middle words. Each language has a list of stop words.

Now it's the time to **check for the entities** in the question. You have to do a [Named Entity Recognition (NER)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition) to get the types and entities. This means: Basically have a lot of training texts, that have all word, to be recognized, tagged. Running NER Training over this texts creates a model and applying the model against the new question should give you types (Restaurant, Location ,...) and entity (Japanese, Toronto, ...) that you can compare against your database. Still, all of the word might be misspelled, so check for similarity.

In the end you still be out of context and have checked one-word-chains. You might need to **compare more then a word**. These word-chains are called [ngram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram). The context overall can be checked further with previous texts and the results. But this will lead you into another universe of **[machine learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning)** algorithms.

All in all: This is not a task that fits into a few weeks sprint...

Answer (score 0):

As you only have three tables, and assuming maybe five text columns per table, a simple approach could be to just search all text columns of all tables for each word. This could even be extended to use a `like` search instead of equals.

You would have to check if you get too many false positives. Maybe you could rank by the number of columns matched.